# Please provide an API "flair"-data call (`/associated` route is inadequate)

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, users

So today I decided to continue refining my JavaScript skills (different post over on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228876/is-it-difficult-to-follow-or-understand-my-javascript-with-my-usage-of-callbacks) if you'd like to review the results) and utilized the Stack Exchange API (v2.2) to write a "user flair" replica.

In case you don't know what the flair that SE provides is:

[image: profile for PerpetualJ on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

The process was a little tedious in places, but only because I am still learning the concept of callbacks in JavaScript. Overall though, I believe they turned out pretty decent (only two shown here).

[image: Wheel] [image: Box]

This got me thinking, in my testing I had to make several separate calls to get all of the information I needed to replicate the flair, but used two primary methods:

- [users/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids)
- [users/{ids}/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users)

Do the future plans for the API include a "user flair" call that would give all of the following information for building custom user flair cards:

- Most Common Display Name or First Encountered

  - I say most common or first encountered because your display name can be different on each SE network.
- Total Reputation
- Total Number of Badges (Gold, Silver, and Bronze)
- Link to SE Network Profile
- SE Network Profile Image URL

  - This is because your profile image can be different on each SE network.
  - Could use the display name here for the above to prevent the multiple networks since all users have to set their SE Network profile to match an existing sub-site, so could be considered the preferred account information.
- Top 10 Sites (or as many as possible up to this)

  - Ordered by reputation descending.
  - Reputation per site.
  - Badge Counts per site (Gold, Silver, and Bronze)
  - Link to Profile on Site

My biggest concern is that it would be underutilized and eventually fall out of support. Perhaps this is why it doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unified call would be nice, but everything you asked for falls into one of 3 categories:

1. It's already in [the `users/{ids}/associated` call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users).
2. It's trivially easy to calculate in the app or script. EG: Total reputation and total badges.
3. Or, it's the kind of information that changes very slowly and should be heavily cached by your app/script for at least a day.

   So the first time you see a user-id, you have to make a few extra calls, but after that your app can, and should, pull that data from its own storage.
   Just update it if it's more than a day old, or better yet, only if the user explicitly requests it. (For most users, their non-numerical flair data is unchanged for years at a time.)